# Chose file button in File upload control of webview doesn't work

Tags: android, webview

I have a file upload control on a web page and displaying it in webview. But Chose file doesn't work. It has no effect. I am using following code for this:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wbvw);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
        //The undocumented magic method override
        //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
        // For Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            WebviewActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

        }

        // For Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser( ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType ) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            WebviewActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                    FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        //For Android 4.1
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            WebviewActivity.this.startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( i, "File Chooser" ), WebviewActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );

        }

    });
```

I tried to run the code with debugger but the methods inside `webView.setWebChromeClient` don't work.

Comment: Add this and try again : webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

Comment: No, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import java.io.*;
import android.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import android.annotation.*;
import java.util.*;
import android.app.*;
import android.provider.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.webkit.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_LOLIPOP = 1;
    private final static int RESULT_CODE_ICE_CREAM = 2;
    private WebView webView;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;

    private String url ="http://up.example.com";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wbvw);
        setUpWebViewDefaults(webView);
        webView.loadUrl(url);



        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                private String TAG;
                // For Android 3.0+
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                    mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),
                                           RESULT_CODE_ICE_CREAM);

                }
                // For Android 3.0+
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                    mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("*/*");
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                                           RESULT_CODE_ICE_CREAM);
                }
                //For Android 4.1
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                    mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),
                                           RESULT_CODE_ICE_CREAM);

                }
                //For Android5.0+
                public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                    if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                    }
                    mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;
                    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        // Create the File where the photo should go
                        File photoFile = null;
                        try {
                            photoFile = createImageFile();
                            takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // Error occurred while creating the File
                            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                        }
                        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                        if (photoFile != null) {
                            mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                                       Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                        } else {
                            takePictureIntent = null;
                        }
                    }
                    Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");
                    Intent[] intentArray;
                    if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                        intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                    } else {
                        intentArray = new Intent[0];
                    }
                    Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_CODE_LOLIPOP);

                    return true;
                }
            });
    }
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        return imageFile;
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setUpWebViewDefaults(WebView webView) {
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        // Enable Javascript
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // Use WideViewport and Zoom out if there is no viewport defined
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        // Enable pinch to zoom without the zoom buttons
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Hide the zoom controls for HONEYCOMB+
            settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        }
        // Enable remote debugging via chrome://inspect
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }
        // We set the WebViewClient to ensure links are consumed by the WebView rather
        // than passed to a browser if it can
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_CODE_ICE_CREAM:
                Uri uri = null;
                if (data != null) {
                    uri = data.getData();
                }
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(uri);
                mUploadMessage = null;
                break;
            case REQUEST_CODE_LOLIPOP:
                Uri[] results = null;
                // Check that the response is a good one
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    if (data == null) {
                        // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                        if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                        }
                    } else {
                        String dataString = data.getDataString();
                        if (dataString != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        }
                    }
                }
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
                mFilePathCallback = null;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This code should work !
**I tried the code and had no problem** [Sony Z3 / android : 6.0.1 ] & [Honor 3c / android : 4.1.1 ].

Source : [Github](https://github.com/chiclaim/android-webview-upload-file/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/chiclaim/webview/MainFragment.java)
<== i edited this code [Change Fragment To Activity] for your use !

Good luck .