# webview chose file android not working

Tags: java, android

i have android project 
using `webview` but my problem thats html file chose file working good from `web` browser but when using the android app `webview` its not working this is my activity_amin code

```
    <WebView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:id="@+id/webView"
    />
```

and this is `MainActivity` java code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webview;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webview.canGoBack()){
            webview.goBack();
        }else {

            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webview.loadUrl("http://softya.com/fitness_time/public/");

    }
}
```

any help please

Comment: Try this webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); instead of webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

Comment: im new in android things could you re right the code to me please

Comment: Use this code : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51331616/10050305

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this as you Mainactivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = findViewById(R.id.web);



    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack()){
        webView.goBack();
    }
    else
    {
        finish();
    }
}
}
```

add this in your Menifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.aashiq.webview">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses- permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

add this in your activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


</WebView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: All the best brother

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the webview settings by

`webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);`

Rewritten code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    webview.loadUrl("http://softya.com/fitness_time/public/");

}
```

Comment: you had taken the webview settings object to enable javascript, You can write the same before setting webviewclient 

`webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());`

Comment: still cant upload file nothing is showing when i hit the chose button this is the image thanks for your replay https://imgur.com/ohblPn6

Comment: I don't know where I am lacking but You should have a look at [This](https://androidexample.com/Open_File_Chooser_With_Camera_Option_In_Webview_File_Option/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=128)  blog this might solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to your error first you clean your code
then create MyWebViewClient class outside of onCreate method.And check you add webview inside of activity xml or not.